# Alembic does not generate tables

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

The first time I run

```
alembic revision --autogenerate -m "init"
```

It generates tables in my database.

After I drop the database, remove the versions of the script, and tried to run alembic again. He does not generate anything anymore.

I have already tried to install alembic again, nothing works. I already searched for a lot of solutions, no one works.

Is there some configuration I'm missing?

Answer (score 6):

Alembic "knows" you already run that migration, then it won't run it again (even if you drop the table or reinstall alembic).

> The process which occurred here included that Alembic first checked if the database had a table called `alembic_version`, and if not, created it. It looks in this table for the current version, if any, and then calculates the path from this version to the version requested, in this case `head`, which is known to be `1975ea83b712`. It then invokes the `upgrade()` method in each file to get to the target revision.
> https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#running-our-first-migration

You need to tell alembic to `downgrade` your migration in order to run it again.
To do that, just call:

```
alembic downgrade -1
```

And then you're able to run your last migration again by calling:

```
alembic upgrade head
```

There's more info [here](https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#relative-migration-identifiers).